# Using JavaPathFinder in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to run Java Pathfinder(JPF) in the Netbeans IDE so I can perform testing. On the JPF website it provides a link to a netbeans site on how to do this but of course this document no longer exist.

**Does anyone know how to do this or can you point me in the right direction?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, seems like not many people are using JPF... Or at least not using JPF and Netbeans.

[NASA's site has a page that will instruct you](http://babelfish.arc.nasa.gov/trac/jpf/wiki/install/netbeans-plugin) (just make sure you download the latest version).

So that you don't need to click a link, I've included the instructions below:

1. Download and install [jpf-core](http://babelfish.arc.nasa.gov/trac/jpf/wiki/projects/jpf-core), e.g. from the [Mercurial repository](http://babelfish.arc.nasa.gov/trac/jpf/wiki/install/repositories)
2. [Optional] Download and install [jpf-shell](http://babelfish.arc.nasa.gov/trac/jpf/wiki/projects/jpf-shell) if you want to use the JPF Swing UI
3. -------------- take a break ---------------
4. Download the **gov-nasa-jpf-netbeans-runjpf.nbm** file attached to this page.
5. From within Netbeans go to Tools->Plugins (Alt+T followed by Alt+g)
6. Select the 'Downloaded' tab
7. Click on the 'Add Plugins...' button (Alt+A)
8. Select the **gov-nasa-jpf-netbeans-runjpf.nbm** file that was downloaded in step 1
9. Select install
10. Agree to the License agreement
11. Restart Netbeans

I would suggest another break between selecting install and agreeing to the license though. NASA has a tendency to expect people to work too hard.